# AndEngine error after import

Tags: android, import, andengine

I have imported AndEngine into Eclipse but I'm always stuck with these errors. I tried to clean it, fix project properties, turn of "Build automatically" but nothing helps. (The same error mark is spread over a lot of packages in the src-folder). What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

[image: Multiple errors after importing AndEngine]

Comment: Window -> Show view -> Problems. What does it say?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. AndEngine uses Java Compiler **1.6** and not **1.5**